# Dropdown Menu Disappearing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I'm having trouble getting my dropdown menu to stay visible. When I mouse over to the menu, the submenu tabs will show up and stay there for a second but then go away. This seems to be a common problem, but I'm not sure what I need to change in my code, nor what html I'd even need to post here to get the problem fixed.

Could anyone look at my site and tell me what is wrong? http://www.studywithstyleblog.com

I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean when you hover over the menubar, the subtabs show there until you try and move onto them - then they disappear?

Comment: Try to add negative margin-top to #menus li ul (line655): -5px would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Now define your** `#menus li ul{top:100%;}`

**as like this**

```
#menus li ul{top:100%;}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the white along the top, you can use: 
border-top: 3px solid #fff;

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! I have a few more issues maybe you could help me with? What do I need to change to center the navigation menu? And if you look closely at the drop down menu tabs, you'll see that there is a thin white band on the left side and bottom. How do I remove this? Thanks in advance! You're awesome! @RohitAzad

Answer (score 0):

you just need to Add "Top:0px;" in "#menus li ul" CSS

```
Updated CSS

#menus li ul {
 z-index: 9999;
 position: absolute;
 left: -999em;
 height: auto;
 width: 175px;
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```